# How to create a dynamic menu in Polymer 1.0 using dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer

First of all, sorry for my english, this is my first question here. I have a problem creating a dynamic menu with dom-repeat, here is my template:

```
<paper-menu class="list" on-iron-select="onMenuSelect" id="mainMenu" >
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="menu" id="iron_pages_app">
       <paper-item on-tap="funcion" data="{{menu}}"><iron-icon icon="{{menu.Icon}}"></iron-icon><span>{{menu.Name}}</span></paper-item>
       <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{menu.Options}}" as="sub" id="iron_pages_app_2">
           <paper-item on-tap="funcion_dos" class="olakease"><span style="padding-left: 3em">{{sub.Name}}</span></paper-item>
                <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{sub.Options}}" as="subDos">
                    <paper-item on-tap="funcion_tres"><span style="padding-left: 6em">{{subDos.Name}}</span></paper-item>
                </template>
        </template>
    </template>
</paper-menu>
```

As you can see this code try to fix the problem that polymer 1.0 has not submenu. The render of data works fine, so my really question is how to get the information of my sub-elements, because if I use:

```
var item = this.$.iron_pages_app.itemForElement(e.target);
```

works fine, but if i try to do the same with "sub-menu elements" don't show nothing. I have tried:

```
var item = this.$$("#iron_pages_app_2").itemForElement(e.target);
var item = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector("#iron_pages_app");
```

Any suggestion? Thanks

#### Edit

Finally I can get the information of each submenus, but I think the way I did is not right one, here is the code:

```
var item = e.model.__data__.sub;
```

where "sub" is the alias of my second dom-repeat, anyone can help me with a better solution? Thanks again.

#### Edit

```
var menu = event.model.menu;
var sub = event.model.sub;
var subDos = event.model.subDos;
```

This works fine, but on third level cant access to information of sub or menu, just doesnt appear.

In "funcion" I need only information about this level.

In "funcion_dos" I need information about this level and first level.

In "funcion_tres" I need information about two previous level.

I hope you can understand me, sorry for my english again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to access the items in your on-tap event handlers you should be able to use event.model.item  Although you've used the **as** attribute to assign different names to the item properties so you'd use those names instead of .item, for example event.model.subDos

Comment: thanks a lot!! you are rigth! this works!! :D Only I can't fully understand how event handlers works, but I'm going to search about it. Thanks again. :D I have another question, why cant get event.model.sub and event.model.menu data when I click funcion_tres? (that is my handler event function on the third level)

Comment: The model in event.model will be populated based on the context the handler is called from. So when function_tres is called its event.model will be populated with the model from your innermost template. One way to handle what you'd like to do is to add something like data-menu="{{menu}}" to your 2nd & 3rd paper-item elements + data-sub="{{sub}}" to your 3rd paper-item element. Then in your event handlers you should be able to use event.model.menu in funcion_dos & funcion_tres + event.model.sub in funcion_tres.